# Component not rendered when calling "replace" in onEnter

Tags: react-router

I am trying to implement simple authentication with `react-router`. I think there is an issue with replace and callback. Consider following code:

1) Routing configuration

```
function getRoutes() {
    return {
        path: "/",
        indexRoute: require("./Home"),
        component: require("./Shared/Layout"),
        onEnter: handleEnter,
        childRoutes: [
            require("./Login"),
            require("./Secured"),
            require("./Any")
        ]
    }
}

function handleEnter(nextState, replace, callback) {
    let state = store.getState()

    if (!state.hasIn(["shared", "user"])) {
        store.dispatch(fetchUser())
            .then(callback)
    }
}
```

2) `./Secured` route configuration

```
export = {
    path: "/secured",
    component: require("./Secured"),
    onEnter(nextState, replace) {
        let state = store.getState()

        if (!state.getIn(["shared", "user"])) {
            replace("/login")
        }
    }
}
```

It should work like this:

1. Fetch user when entering root route (async operation, we need callback)
2. Go to `/secured` and check whether user is authenticated when entering the route
3. If user is not authenticated go to `/login`

The problem is that the `/login` page will not be rendered. The URL is changed to `/login`, but nothing is displayed and there are no error messages in console. When I remove `callback` parameter from the root route configuration, it starts working as expected.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it was really stupid :) I've forgot to call `callback` when user is already authenticated.